# Intellij doesn't run with idea64.exe but runs by idea.but

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

I installed Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.3.2 but I can't run idea64.exe, it's just not happening.
When I use idea.but it's run and

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

appears in command line

It's my java version:

> java 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

When i try to run idea64.exe, it doesn't create new processes.

Ther is logs when I run idea.bat:

> ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,546 [     25]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-203.7148.57, 26 Jan 2021 03:24)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,548 [     27]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,551 [     30]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,551 [     30]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,552 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx2024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\idea64.exe.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\MarcinP\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\MarcinP\java_error_in_idea.hprof -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2020.3 -Didea.jre.check=true
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,552 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: C:\Programy\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\jbr\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Programy\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Programy\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin;C:\Programy\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Programy\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Programy\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin;C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Programy\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin;;;.
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,553 [     32]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - CPU cores: 8; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@774c7618[Running, parallelism = 7, size = 1, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 7, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@1c1f8d8e
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,554 [     33]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: C:\Programy\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\jbr\bin
> 2021-03-02 17:40:06,576 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=pl_PL JNU=Cp1250 file.encoding=Cp1250
> idea.config.path=C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
> idea.system.path=C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
> idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins
> idea.log.path=C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\log
> 2021-03-02 17:40:07,029 [    508]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 453 ms
> 2021-03-02 17:40:07,033 [    512]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational
> 2021-03-02 17:40:09,743 [   3222]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: IDEA CORE (203.7148.57), Dependency Management Api for External Build Tools (203.7148.57), com.intellij.platform.images (203.7148.57), JetBrains maven model api classes (203.7148.57), JetBrains Repository Search (203.7148.57), HTML Tools (203.7148.57), Perforce (203.7148.57), Refactor-X (203.7148.57), Subversion (203.7148.57), XPathView + XSLT (203.7148.57), XSLT Debugger (203.7148.57), Smali Support (203.7148.57), IDE Settings Sync (203.7148.57), Machine Learning Code Completion (203.7148.57), Configuration Script (203.7148.57), Copyright (203.7148.57), CSS (203.7148.57), W3C Validators (203.7148.57), Less (203.7148.57), Sass (203.7148.57), Stylus (203.7148.57), Windows 10 Light Theme (203.7148.57), Properties (203.7148.57), Gradle (203.7148.57), Gradle Dependency Updater Implementation (203.7148.57), Resource Bundle Editor (203.7148.57), FTP/SFTP Connectivity (ex. Remote Hosts Access) (203.7148.57), Mercurial (203.7148.57), WebP Support (203.7148.57), EditorConfig (203.7148.57), Haml (203.7148.57), Terminal (203.7148.57), Git (203.7148.57), ChangeReminder (203.7148.57), SSH Remote Run (203.7148.57), WSL Support Framework (203.7148.57), Shell Script (203.7148.57), TextMate Bundles (203.7148.57), YAML (203.7148.57), Settings Repository (203.7148.57), IDE Features Trainer (203.7148.57), Java (203.7148.57), Ant (203.7148.57), Bytecode Viewer (203.7148.57), Docker (203.7148.57), JUnit (203.7148.57), Lombok (203.7148.57), ZKM-Unscramble (203.7148.57), Spring AOP/@AspectJ (203.7148.57), UML (203.7148.57), Dependency Structure Matrix (203.7148.57), Guice (203.7148.57), Java Internationalization (203.7148.57), UI Designer (203.7148.57), Java IDE Customization (203.7148.57), Microservices Application Configuration (203.7148.57), Microservices UAST (203.7148.57), Velocity (203.7148.57), Java Stream Debugger (203.7148.57), Eclipse Interoperability (203.7148.57), Java Bytecode Decompiler (203.7148.57), Task Management (203.7148.57), GitHub (203.7148.57), Time Tracking (203.7148.57), Performance Testing (203.7148.57), Shared Indexes (203.7148.57), Next File Prediction (203.7148.57), Recommenders for Java and Python (203.7148.57), IntelliLang (203.7148.57), TestNG (203.7148.57), Code Coverage for Java (203.7148.57), Emma (203.7148.57), Groovy (203.7148.57), Maven (203.7148.57), AspectJ (203.7148.57), Gradle-Java (203.7148.57), Plugin DevKit (203.7148.57), Gradle Extension (203.7148.57), Frameworks Starters (203.7148.57), Gradle-Maven (203.7148.57), Reactive Streams (Reactor, RxJava) (203.7148.57), Performance Testing (Maven) (203.7148.57), Gradle DSL API (203.7148.57), JavaFX (203.7148.57), Gherkin (203.7148.57), Cucumber for Java (203.7148.57), Cucumber for Groovy (203.7148.57), Markdown (203.7148.57), Grazie (203.7148.57), JavaScript and TypeScript (203.7148.57), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (203.7148.57), TSLint (203.7148.57), Angular and AngularJS (203.7148.57), Database Tools and SQL (203.7148.57), Java SQL Libraries (203.7148.57), Persistence Frameworks (203.7148.57), Java EE Platform (203.7148.57), JavaScript Debugger (203.7148.57), Node.js (203.7148.57), Spy-js (203.7148.57), CoffeeScript (203.7148.57), Kotlin (203-1.4.10-release-IJ7148.5), Gradle DSL Implementation For Kotlin (203.7148.57), Android (10.4.0.203.7148.57), Java EE: Bean Validation (203.7148.57), Java EE: Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI) (203.7148.57), Helidon (203.7148.57), Java EE: Batch Applications (203.7148.57), Java EE: Persistence (JPA) (203.7148.57), Java EE: Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) (203.7148.57), Hibernate (203.7148.57), Java EE: Application Servers (203.7148.57), GlassFish (203.7148.57), WildFly (203.7148.57), Debugger Support for JSP (JSR45) (203.7148.57), Jetty (203.7148.57), Tomcat and TomEE (203.7148.57), WebSphere (203.7148.57), WebLogic (203.7148.57), Java EE: Web/Servlets (203.7148.57), Java Server Pages (JSP) (203.7148.57), Java EE: Server Faces (JSF) (203.7148.57), Java EE: Message Service (JMS) (203.7148.57), Java EE: WebSockets (203.7148.57), JBoss Frameworks Base (203.7148.57), Drools (203.7148.57), Arquillian (203.7148.57), Java EE: Gradle Integration (203.7148.57), Spring (203.7148.57), Spring Security (203.7148.57), Thymeleaf (203.7148.57), Spring Data (203.7148.57), Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS) (203.7148.57), Spring Web Services (203.7148.57), Grails (203.7148.57), FreeMarker (203.7148.57), Spring Batch (203.7148.57), Spring Messaging (203.7148.57), Spring Integration Patterns (203.7148.57), Spring WebSocket (203.7148.57), Spring OSGi (203.7148.57), Maven Extension (203.7148.57), HTTP Client (203.7148.57), Spring MVC (203.7148.57), Spring Web Flow (203.7148.57), Spring Boot (203.7148.57), Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) (203.7148.57), Quarkus (203.7148.57), Micronaut (203.7148.57), Java HTTP Clients (203.7148.57), OpenAPI Specifications (203.7148.57)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:09,744 [   3223]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: Choose Runtime (1.2)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,224 [   3703]   INFO - m.intellij.util.io.StorageLock - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1937
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,238 [   3717]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - uninterruptible FileChannels will be used for indexes
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,246 [   3725]   INFO - intellij.diagnostic.JitWatcher - JIT compilation state checking enabled
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,279 [   3758]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,386 [   3865]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,394 [   3873]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,510 [   3989]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start.updateInitStatus ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,515 [   3994]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED (1ms) ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,523 [   4002]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,621 [   4100]   INFO - lij.impl.ConversionServiceImpl - conversion will be performed because at least C:\Users\MarcinP\IdeaProjects\nowytest.idea\compiler.xml is changed (oldLastModified=1614702801, newLastModified=1614702930)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,720 [   4199]   INFO - BridgeProjectLifecycleListener - Using workspace model to open project
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,840 [   4319]   INFO - orm.impl.SharedIndexZipStorage - Shared Indexes Storage is opened: , chunks: []
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,902 [   4381]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Programy\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin\fsnotifier64.exe
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,961 [   4440]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational.
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,963 [   4442]   INFO - .cloudConfig.CloudConfigClient - === Get cloud config URL: https://cloudconfig.jetbrains.com/cloudconfig/files ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:10,973 [   4452]   INFO - pi.vfs.impl.wsl.WslFileWatcher - WSL file watcher: C:\Programy\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin\fsnotifier-wsl
> 2021-03-02 17:40:11,210 [   4689]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Initialized from default code style settings.
> 2021-03-02 17:40:11,243 [   4722]   INFO - on.JpsProjectModelSynchronizer - Workspace model loaded without cache. Loading real project state into workspace model. Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 5,4,Idea Thread Group]
> 2021-03-02 17:40:11,287 [   4766]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus.value: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:12,848 [   6327]   INFO - leBasedIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done: 2468
> 2021-03-02 17:40:13,074 [   6553]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done: 225
> 2021-03-02 17:40:13,178 [   6657]   INFO - penapi.application.Experiments - Experimental features enabled for user: wsl.p9.support, wsl.p9.show.roots.in.file.chooser, wsl.execute.with.wsl.exe, inline.browse.button, linux.native.menu, recent.and.edited.files.together, show.create.new.element.in.popup, search.everywhere.mixed.results, copy.reference.popup, i18n.match.actions, editor.reader.mode, edit.run.configurations.while.dumb, new.large.text.file.viewer, terminal.shell.command.handling, property.value.inplace.editing
> 2021-03-02 17:40:13,479 [   6958]   INFO -              PerformancePlugin - Performance Plugin is in silent mode
> 2021-03-02 17:40:13,531 [   7010]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release
> 2021-03-02 17:40:13,727 [   7206]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 10 millis (read time: 1)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:13,807 [   7286]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8
> 2021-03-02 17:40:14,323 [   7802]   INFO - oudConfig.StatusBarInfoManager - === StatusBar.update another widget: null ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:14,324 [   7803]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.updateInitStatus ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:14,596 [   8075]   INFO - oudConfig.StatusBarInfoManager - === StatusBar.start create ===
> 2021-03-02 17:40:14,895 [   8374]   INFO - llij.database.util.SqlDialects - SQL dialects initialized in 0 ms
> 2021-03-02 17:40:14,968 [   8447]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 107ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
> 2021-03-02 17:40:14,992 [   8471]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Programy/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
> 2021-03-02 17:40:15,071 [   8550]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> 2021-03-02 17:40:15,071 [   8550]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> 2021-03-02 17:40:15,072 [   8551]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> 2021-03-02 17:40:15,155 [   8634]   INFO - redIndexChunkConfigurationImpl - Chunk bundled-js-predefined-ffdd448c697d-9d1e29453470-JavaScript-IU-203.7148.57 is registered for project 'nowytest: matching: (fb=33, stub=75), incompatible: (fb=0, stub=0), unknown: (fb=9, stub=9),
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,524 [  10003]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,525 [  10004]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Programy/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/lib/util.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,525 [  10004]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,525 [  10004]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,525 [  10004]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,751 [  10230]   INFO - .OnDiskSharedIndexChunkLocator - Scanning C:\Users\MarcinP\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\shared-index for shared indexes...
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,754 [  10233]   INFO - SharedIndexPostStartupActivity - Attached 1 pre-built shared indexes: bundled-js-predefined-ffdd448c697d-9d1e29453470-JavaScript-IU-203.7148.57
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,944 [  10423]   INFO - ProjectRootPostStartUpActivity - C:/Users/MarcinP/IdeaProjects/nowytest/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false
> 2021-03-02 17:40:16,958 [  10437]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found
> 2021-03-02 17:40:17,025 [  10504]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 3504ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
> 2021-03-02 17:40:17,161 [  10640]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 6463 ms
> 2021-03-02 17:40:17,254 [  10733]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Programy/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
> 2021-03-02 17:40:17,337 [  10816]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> 2021-03-02 17:40:17,337 [  10816]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> 2021-03-02 17:40:17,337 [  10816]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> 2021-03-02 17:40:18,176 [  11655]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Sent token to maven server
> 2021-03-02 17:40:18,659 [  12138]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> 2021-03-02 17:40:18,660 [  12139]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Programy/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/lib/util.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
> 2021-03-02 17:40:18,660 [  12139]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
> 2021-03-02 17:40:18,660 [  12139]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> 2021-03-02 17:40:18,660 [  12139]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> 2021-03-02 17:40:20,571 [  14050]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 5603ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
> 2021-03-02 17:40:20,578 [  14057]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to index
> 2021-03-02 17:40:22,264 [  15743]   INFO - gnostic.WindowsDefenderChecker - Windows Defender status: not used
> 2021-03-02 17:43:10,531 [ 184010]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Terminating: 25400/Maven36ServerImpl5461fe7f

Anybody know solution this problem?
I will be very grateful for any help

Comment: It's just a warning. Do you see idea.exe in processes list? Please check if any logs are recorded (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Comment: @y.bedrov I edited my post by adding more info. See now

Comment: Are there any crashdumps (e.g. "C:\Users\MarcinP\java_error_in_idea_%p.log" )? Have you checked Windows Events log? Also you may try to open command line and run idea.bat from "<ide_installation_path>/bin" folder.

Comment: There are't any crashdumps. I checked Windows Events but i found nothing about my problem. Yes,  I can run  idea.bat by command line :) but problem is idea64.exe not work

Comment: Please try to clan folders use by IDE (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and reinstall IDE.

Comment: Ok, problem is solved.. I installed this one: [link](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe ) and idea64.exe starts.